# Calling method without object

Tags: java

I have built a small (and 3 methods only!) api for myself, and I want to be able to call it like how you would call a method in Powerbot (A Runescape botting tool (I use it, but for programming purposes, not for actual cheating purposes)), without creating an Object of the file you'd require. How would i be able to do this?

Comment: Make the methods static - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963983/how-and-where-to-use-static-modifier-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the static keyword when importing your class, you can use its methods as if they belong to the class you're importing them to. See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

And of course your "api methods" need to be static as well.

Comment: The prerequisite of this is declaring the desired class members `static`.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to create static methods, so you will need to do something like so:

```
public class A
{
    public static void foo()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then, you can call them like so:

```
public class B
{
    ...
    A.foo();
}
```

Note however that `static` methods need to be self contained.

EDIT: As recommended in one of the answers below, you can make it work like so:

```
package samples.examples
public class Test
{
    public static void A()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then do this:

```
import static sample.examples.Test.A;

public class Test2
{
    ...
    A();
}
```

Comment: What i'm asking is, is it possible to be able to call them, without having any kind of declaration? Like using the "A.foo();" Is it possible to just call it like foo();?

Comment: @Nathan: To just call `foo()` you will need to place it in the same class.

Comment: So there's no way at all to get rid of the class declaration?

Comment: @NathanKreider: What you are after seems after all possible. I have ammended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found out for me was to `extend` my activity (If i said it right)...

**MAIN CLASS**

```
public class myMainActivity extends myMiniApi{
...
}
```

I think this is a better way (my opinion) to do this, Just call your method like you normally would as if it were in the same class. example:

```
randomMethod();
```