# Search and Delete Function in Singly priority linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue, singly-linked-list

I want to perform a search operation in a priority linked list in java, I have already write a search and delete method for that but i am facing difficulties in calling these methods to my main function? here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.*;
```

class Node {

```
public static Node next = null;
public static int item = 0;

public Node(int item) {
    this.item = item;
}
```

}

public class Main {

```
static PriorityQueue<String> stringQueue;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    stringQueue = new PriorityQueue<String>();

    stringQueue.add("1");
    stringQueue.add("2");
    stringQueue.add("3");
    stringQueue.add("6");
    stringQueue.add("6");
    stringQueue.add("5");
    stringQueue.add("9");
    stringQueue.add("8");
    stringQueue.add("7");
    stringQueue.add("4");

    while (stringQueue.size() > 0)
        System.out.println(stringQueue.remove());
    Node head = null;

}

public static Node searchNodeFIFO(Node head, int item) {
    System.out.println("In Search Node");

    Node cHead = head;

    while (cHead != null) {
        if (cHead.item == item)
            return cHead;

        cHead = cHead.next;
    }

    return null;
}

public Node deleteNodeFIFO(Node head, int item) {
    System.out.println("In Delete Node");

    if (head.item == item)
        return head.next;

    Node cNode = head;
    Node nNode = head.next;

    while (nNode != null) {
        if (nNode.item == item) {
            cNode.next = nNode.next;
            break;
        } else {
            cNode = nNode;
            nNode = nNode.next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

public void printLinkList(Node head) {
    while (head != null) {
        System.out.println(head.item);
        head = head.next;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately "I am facing difficulties ..." is a statement, not a question. Please be specific about the problem you're having.

Comment: I must say the provided code seems very unhelpful; what is `head`? Why is it an attribute of main? Why are the `Node` attributes static? Every instance of `Node` will share values; every item in the structure that holds the Nodes (which you've not provided) will be the same.

Comment: `while (stringQueue.size() > 0) System.out.println(stringQueue.remove());` - you just removed all of them, there's nothing left to search. Also, you're mixing data structures, it appears that you shouldn't be using a `PriorityQueue` at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess and figure it's because of the attributes in your `Node` class.
Why are you declaring them as static?
This causes every instance of `Node` to share the same attribute (`value` and `next`) values.

Every item in the structure that holds them will be the same.

Trying removing the `static` modifier from your `Node` attribute declarations.

See [how and where to use static modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963983/how-and-where-to-use-static-modifier-in-java)