# Instantion with increment field

Tags: java

I have class ServiceCard with the field `private int  cardID`, and when I make one or more instances of ServiceCard, I want the first instance have `cardID=1`, the second instance have `cardID=2`, etc.

I try to make cardID to static, but it didn't work.

```
public class ServiceCard {
    private static int cardID;

    public ServiceCard() {
        setCardID(getCardID() + 1);
    }   

    public static int getCardID() {
        return cardID;
    }

    public static void setCardID(int cardID) {
        ServiceCard.cardID = cardID;
    }
}
```

When I make a test :

```
ServiceCard card = new ServiceCard();
System.out.println(card.getCardID());

ServiceCard card2= new ServiceCard();
System.out.println(card2.getCardID());

System.out.println(card.getCardID());
```

Console:

```
1
2
2
```

Comment: You aren't incrementing `cardId`. Use `cardID++` instead of `getCardID() + 1)`

Comment: please read SO before asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963983/how-and-where-to-use-static-modifier-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Making the *cardID* `static` itself won't work. Because then, all your instances would have the same *cardID* at any given moment.

You need to have another `static` field in your class, which will be used to assign incremental values to `id`. Also, you can use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead, which is better suited as atomic counter, in case of multithreaded application:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ServiceCard {

    private int cardID;
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public ServiceCard() {
        cardID = counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}

ServiceCard card1 = new ServiceCard();
ServiceCard card2 = new ServiceCard();

System.out.println(card1.getCardID());  // 1
System.out.println(card2.getCardID());  // 2
```