# Is there any advantage to using a object based run() method instead of the static main?

Tags: java, object, static, program-entry-point

Is there any advantage to using the following code

```
public void run(){
     //Code
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Main().run();
}
```

instead of

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //code
}
```

For small programs that you write during a introduction to programming?

I can't see how this will offer any memory saving or performance?

Comment: I can only say Java is OOP language, but its a personal preference, as far as I know.

Comment: I guess it's useful if your object is also something that is used outside of this particular application. I would have thought it would use a little bit more memory but not enough for it to make any difference. Also I guess some peoples style is to enter a non static context as soon as possible.

Comment: It's also useful to separate the part of the code that deals with parsing command line arguments from the "business logic". The former can stay in `main` (or inside of the main class), the latter can live in another class.

Comment: Some more (not really compelling) discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812496/java-only-static-members-in-main-class?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instructional purposes, or really any other purposes, the difference in memory is negligible.  It's also not any more object-oriented to hide code in sub-routines, if the data that code accesses is the same either way and there are no other sub-routines.

So, unless there's actually more to your code than you're showing, I would use the simpler variant without the run function.