# How to call an entire class from another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am a beginner in Java. I have two packages in my current project. Each of the packages have two classes called the "packageClassOne" and "packageClassTwo".

The packageClassTwo has a constructor and other public methods.

I want to call the PackageClassTwo from an if statment located in the PackageClassOne. My code looks something like this

packageClassOne:

```
 public class packageClassOne {
    public void selectComponent(boolen) {
       if(/* check condition*) {
          packageClassTwo value = new packageClassTwo();
       }
    }
 }
```

packageClassTwo:

```
 public class packageClassTwo {

    public packageClassTwo(String name){     //Constructor
         int length = name.length();
     }

   public String CreateWord(){
      /*functionality ofthis method*/
   }

    public String CreateSentence(){
      /*functionality ofthis method*/
   }
 }
```

The problem is that everytime I call the packageClassTwo from my packageClassOne it tries to call the constructor instead of calling the class itself. I want to call the entire packageClassTwo instead of just the constructor.

Can somebody help me please? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What do you mean with "call the entire packageClassTwo instead of just the constructor"?

Comment: If the constructor not called, how do you construct the object of  packageClassTwo?

Comment: @Oscar I want to call the entire class packageClassTwo so that all the methods within ithat class are executed.

Comment: @Goldengirl Then you need to first, instantiate the class. Second, call the desired methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java is an object oriented language, you have to have a mindset of dealing with instances that are realizations of the classes you defined. These are the objects.

So if you want to call a method from `packageClassTwo` class, you first create an object of `packageClassTwo`. You seem to be trying to do just this. Once you have the object, you can call its methods. For example

```
//Instantiate an object by calling the constructor
packageClassTwo object = new packageClassTwo(string);
//Now call its methods
String val = object.CreateWord()
```

There is no such thing as "calling a class". You call methods of objects of a class.

Occasionally, there might be a well founded need to call methods of a class without initializing objects. Look into [static methods and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963983/how-and-where-to-use-static-modifier-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call all methods of `packageClassTwo` you have to do it explicitly

```
packageClassTwo pct = new packageClassTwo("");
pct.CreateWord();
pct.CreateSentence();
```

If you allways want the 2 methods to be called when you create a new packageClassTwo object, than you can just add the calls to the constructor

```
public packageClassTwo(String name) {     
     int length = name.length();
     pct.CreateWord();
     pct.CreateSentence();
 }
```

**Edit:**

Note that in the second case, if you end up only calling the 2 methods from inside the constructor, it is better to make them private.

As a sidenote, it is a general convention in java to have class names start with a upper case letter : `PackageClassTwo` not `packageClassTwo`, and method names to start with lower case `createWord` not `CreateWord`. This wll make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call all the methods from the packageClassTwo, call them from the packageClassTwo constructor

```
 public packageClassTwo(String name)
 {    
     int length = name.length();
     CreateWorld();
     CreateSentence();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code will run without compiling errors.because you did not declare the constructor `packageClassTwo()`.

Comment: A default no argument constructor will be added at the compile time.

Comment: No.in fact, your IDE will show you red error at once, if you try to new instance with default constructor.

Comment: the default constructor only be added if you didn't define any constructor.

Comment: You are right, the default constructor wil be added to packageClassOne and not packageClassTwo. I missread your answer.  On the other hand, packageClassTwo has a constructor with String parameter, so your answer is still incorrent.