# Parallel execution is not working in Appium

Tags: java, appium, parallel-execution

I am providing the udid and it's ruining but it is not executing my tests, it just reset sometime and then stop working.

I am using the:-
java-1.8
appium-6.1.0
appium server- gui based version 1.13.0 
testng- 6.8

If I don't initialize loadconfig there it is not initializing the driver and beforesuite annotation is not even working.

testng: it's testng file

```
    <test name="Emulator">
        <parameter name="runAs" value="grid"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platform" value="mobile"></parameter>
        <parameter name="runOn" value="emulator-5554"></parameter>
        <parameter name="port" value="4726"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="TestCase.Login"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Samsung J7">
        <parameter name="runAs" value="grid"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platform" value="mobile"></parameter>
        <parameter name="runOn" value="52039763fe37a3eb"></parameter>
        <parameter name="port" value="4729"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="TestCase.Login"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

setCapability file: It is used to set the capability

```
@Parameters({"runOn"})
    @BeforeSuite
    public static void loadConfigProp(@Optional("chrome_normal") String runOn) throws IOException
    {//Importing the files
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\Properties\\"+"data.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
        app= new File(prop.getProperty("app.path"));
        //APPLICATION_NAME = prop.getProperty("application.path");
        BASE_PKG = prop.getProperty("base.pkg");
        APP_ACTIVITY = prop.getProperty("application.activity");        AUTOMATION_INSTRUMENTATION=prop.getProperty("automation.instumentation");
        DEVICE_NAME=prop.getProperty("device.name");

        PLATFORM_NAME=prop.getProperty("platform.name");

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,
                Base.PLATFORM_NAME);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
                Base.APP_ACTIVITY);
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");
        capabilities.setCapability("fullReset","false");
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,
                Base.BASE_PKG);
        if(runOn.equals("52039763fe37a3eb"))
            {
                capabilities.setCapability("udid", "52039763fe37a3eb");
                driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4729/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            }else if(runOn.equals("emulator-5554"))
            {
                capabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
                driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4726/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            }
    }
```

Loading config: Calling load config file

```
 @BeforeTest
    public void start() throws IOException {
        Base b= new Base();
        b.loadConfigProp("52039763fe37a3eb");
        b.loadConfigProp("emulator-5554");
        driver=b.getDriver();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963983/how-and-where-to-use-static-modifier-in-java) access modifier from your `loadConfigProp` function
2. Consider putting your AndroidDriver instances into [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

It is hard to tell what else is wrong without seeing your full code along with TestNG configuration so in the meantime you can check out [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices) article which contains tips and tricks along with the project you can use as a basis for your tests.